# RaspberryPi "failed to acquire camera" after a couple of dozen successful captures

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, raspberry-pi-zero

Unfortunately, what I thought was a super simple timelapse script is failing rapidly.  The crontab launches the script every minute between 06:00 and 20:59, but for some reason, it's managing only a few and then dying.  To give it the best chance, I even set up the crontab to also reboot at 05:55, knowing that seems to fix whatever is going wrong with the camera, but alas, this morning it's managed 20 photos and then given up.
When I try to run the script manually after the failures begin, it seems libcamera is saying "failed to acquire camera".  As I say, a reboot seems to resolve this :/

My capture.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

SPACE=$(df / -m | awk '/[0-9]%/{print $(NF-2)}')

if [ "$SPACE" -gt "1024" ]
  then
    DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")
    libcamera-jpeg -n -o /home/apbarratt/captures/$DATE.jpg
  else
    echo "Disk space too low."
fi
```

My Crontab (`sudo crontab -e`):

```
* 6-20 * * * sh /home/apbarratt/capture.sh 2>&1
55 5 * * * root reboot
```

The output from running `./capture.sh` after failures start happening:

```
./capture.sh
[11:01:20.747212098] [5076]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:299 libcamera v0.0.4+22-923f5d70
[11:01:20.908320544] [5077]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1476 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[11:01:20.910700063] [5076]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:841 Pipeline handler in use by another process
ERROR: *** failed to acquire camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 ***
```

The output when it's working after a reboot:

```
./capture.sh
[0:01:10.299957000] [771]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:299 libcamera v0.0.4+22-923f5d70
[0:01:10.457443000] [772]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1476 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[0:01:10.462446000] [771]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1028 configuring streams: (0) 1296x972-YUV420
[0:01:10.465075000] [772]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:851 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 1296x972-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1296x972-pGAA
[0:01:15.638456000] [771]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1028 configuring streams: (0) 2592x1944-YUV420 (1) 2592x1944-SGBRG10_CSI2P
[0:01:15.645574000] [772]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:851 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 2592x1944-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 2592x1944-pGAA
Still capture image received
```

The hardware is a Raspberry Pi Zero with the official and original ZeroCam.

Comment: Have you checked open files with `lsof`?

Comment: I have not.  Just tried it within the captures folder and it says the command is not found so I'm going to quickly look it up, I assume it's something I can apt install...

Comment: Okay, installed and run.  Very large output.  I'll have a read through to see if anything obvious stands out...

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious.
I've tried running `lsof .` within the captures folder and can see three processes.  One for bash and two for lsof.
So I tried `lsof ./*` and no processes come up at all.
I then tried running it on my script: `lsof capture.sh` and nothing comes up.

Comment: Spotted this suggestion on another forum, `sudo lsof | grep /dev/video` and this one comes up with oodles of results.

Comment: You can count those oodles with `wc -l`. You can then compare them to the `ulimit` the process has for open files. I suspect that would be the issue. :)

Comment: If this is indeed the issue I'd suggest closing this question here, and asking it on [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or on the [Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) as this is not a programming question but a configuration question. Unless your code is what is causing all those open files.

Comment: I couldn't post the full output in the comments here, but I've added it to the forum post as it appears the other poster didn't really find a sensible fix other than killing the processes in another cronjob after their first one, which I don't think would work particularly well at the single minute level
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2129219#p2129219

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254985/discussion-between-uberhumus-and-apbarratt).

Comment: Ah, I knew I'd got something wrong, I was expecting it to ask something like "what category do you want this posted in" . Thanks, I'll see if I can tidy this up.

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to figure out why, but it seems libcamera-jpeg isn't releasing the camera properly every time.  The process just seems to hang and nothing else can access it whilst that's happening.

After seeing this forum post on the topic here: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2129219#p2129219

I followed the advice of the poster and am killing the process using `pkill -f libcamera-jpeg`

They were doing so with another cron job but I've just added it to my script, so the process is killed (if it's running) at the start of my script.  It feels hacky, but without any understanding of why the issue is happening in the first place and how to prevent it, it's a solution that's working.

```
#!/bin/sh 

pkill -f libcamera-jpeg 

SPACE=$(df / -m | awk '/[0-9]%/{print $(NF-2)}') 

if [ "$SPACE" -gt "1024" ] 
then 
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S") 
libcamera-jpeg -n -o /home/apbarratt/captures/$DATE.jpg 
else 
echo "Disk space too low." 
fi
```